# Rubbery Naan bread

Tags: baking, bread, flour, mixing, kneading

i can't find anywhere on the internet on how to fix naan bread that is rubbery.

My customer has switch to a self raising flour which has a higher  protein level about 10.5%  and absorbs more water.

i've had the following suggestions

mix the dough for a shorter time
add less yoghurt because it has protein in it
add sugar
add more water

if anyone can shine some more light that would be great.

Andy

Comment: Self raising as in "with baking powder"?

Comment: And could you describe the previous process and the changes? Did you use yeast and/or a starter (or leftover dough)?

Answer (score 1):

As you likely know, the rubberiness comes gluten. Gluten is formed when the proteins glutenin and gliadin in the flour get wet and are kneaded— as far as I know, the protein in the yoghurt shouldn't make any difference in the formation of gluten. To reduce gluten, you need to reduce the glutenin and gliadin in the mixture, reduce the kneading (tough when rolling or stretching a flat bread,) let the gluten rest in a cool environment before it's cooked, or add fat.

The easiest and most effective method would probably be to replace some of the flour with corn starch to reduce the overall protein percentage in the mixture. The next-easiest method would be to use much higher-fat yoghurt if you're using a low-fat yoghurt or add butter/oil to the dough.

Good luck!